# Strange rendering of latex fragments in org-mode buffer

Tags: xetex, luatex, org-mode

This is a strange rendering problem I haven't seen before. In an org buffer with many latex fragments, when rendered, each image rendered has at the top in faint black letters: TLT TLT, and then under it
is the properly rendered latex expression about a line or a line and a half below. I am using luatex for rendering org mode latex fragments. I am just curious if anyone has seen this before? I've used org and tex together in org-mode for years and haven't experienced this before. It is a luatex, xetex, or unicode issue of some kind?

Please forget my previous updates as they were incorrect and superfluous.

Update: Ok, finally I found the difference - the cause of failure:

`\( S \)` fails with the TLT TLT rendered above the expression as described above.

`\(S\)` succeeds as does `\(S \)`.

in any org file using my Emacs org configuration.

I don't think latex, xetex, luatex care about there being a space after  and before the inline expression delimiter. It must therefore be a problem with my org-mode configuration for previewing latex fragments? Looking into it with the Emacs crowd: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59288/org-preview-latex-rendering-weirdness-when-a-space-after-initial-inline-expressi

Comment: TLT is the luatex  name (from omega) for the default latin script writing direction left to right, top to bottom, but how that is showing up in your output I could not guess with no example..

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, that helped. I've updated the question.

Comment: Here is the conclusion of this with an answer spurred by @David Carlisle's answer above. Thanks David! https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59292/can-you-render-the-latex-math-expressions-in-the-following-file-successfully-ht